# Display more information after clicking in row of table in angular

Tags: html, angular

I have a table which contains list of informations from the database my problem how I can display the information of each line ,below this line,in other words i want more information about this line.

I have already managed to display the information but below the table .

```
<tbody>
<ng-container>
<tr *ngFor="let affectation  of affectations">

<td>{{affectation[1]}}</td>
<td>{{affectation[2] }}</td>
<td>{{affectation[3]}}</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btaction"
(click)="getAffectationForEmploye(affectation[0])">Actionner</button></td>
--after clicking show more information about the line of table 1
</tr>

--show informations about the line of table 1 
<tr [hidden]="!visionnerTableau" class="trDisplay" *ngFor="let affecter of affecters">
<td>{{affecter.fiche.nom}}</td>
<td>{{affecter.fiche.prenom}}</td>
<td>{{affecter.fiche.produit.nom_produit}}</td>
</tr>

</ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should place the first for loop on the ng-container and if you just want to show information of 1 line at a time, you can use the index for this and a selectedItemIndex in your component and probably an ngIf instead of hidden to only invoke getAffectationForEmploye for the selected item. So something like this:

```
<tbody>
<ng-container *ngFor="let affectation  of affectations; let i = index;">
<tr>
<td>{{affectation[1]}}</td>
<td>{{affectation[2] }}</td>
<td>{{affectation[3]}}</td>
<td><button type="button" class="btaction"
(click)="selectedItemIndex = index;">Actionner</button></td>
--after clicking show more information about the line of table 1
</tr>

--show informations about the line of table 1 
<ng-container *ngIf="selectedItemIndex === index">
<tr class="trDisplay" *ngFor="let affecter of getAffectationForEmploye(affectation[0])">
<td>{{affecter.fiche.nom}}</td>
<td>{{affecter.fiche.prenom}}</td>
<td>{{affecter.fiche.produit.nom_produit}}</td>
</tr>
</ng-container>

</ng-container>
</tbody>
```